# 2 functions init inside one JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I try to combine 2 defer functions init to 1 Java script.

I actually try now combine another one but he make conflict and the JS very heavy. this is 2 different script + 1 is not so important (but if you guys succeed help me combine all of them perfectly is be better).

This the code I try put after I edit him 2( 2 functions init ):

```
function init() {
    var imgDefer = document.querySelectorAll('div[data-src]');
    var style = "background-image: url({url})";
    for (var i = 0; i < imgDefer.length; i++) {

        imgDefer[i].setAttribute('style', style.replace("{url}", imgDefer[i].getAttribute('data-src')));

    }
    imgDefer = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
    for (var i = 0; i < imgDefer.length; i++) {
        if (imgDefer[i].getAttribute('data-src')) {
            imgDefer[i].setAttribute('src', imgDefer[i].getAttribute('data-src'));
        }
    }
}
window.onload = init;
```

---

I make him a short too... he defers the images but slower the site:

```
function init(){for(var t=document.querySelectorAll("div[data-src]"),e=0;e<t.length;e++)t[e].setAttribute("style","background-image: url({url})".replace("{url}",t[e].getAttribute("data-src")));t=document.getElementsByTagName("img");for(e=0;e<t.length;e++)t[e].getAttribute("data-src")&&t[e].setAttribute("src",t[e].getAttribute("data-src"))}window.onload=init;
```

(you can look the code is deferred on the website: locksmithunit.com)

but he very slow on the page load.

---

and this all the original codes... these codes are for deferring images
and the last one is for "frame"

the frame not so important. and if you can give me him separately because 
have pages I don't have iframe.

please help me guys, i very lost.
I most combine at least the first 2 scripts from all the 3 I send now:

```
<script>
function init() {
var imgDefer = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
for (var i=0; i<imgDefer.length; i++) {
if(imgDefer[i].getAttribute('data-src')) {
imgDefer[i].setAttribute('src',imgDefer[i].getAttribute('data-src'));

} } }
window.onload = init;
<script> 


<script>
function init() {
  var imgDefer = document.querySelectorAll('div[data-src]');
  var style = "background-image: url({url})";
  for (var i = 0; i < imgDefer.length; i++) {

    imgDefer[i].setAttribute('style', style.replace("{url}", imgDefer[i].getAttribute('data-src')));

  }
}
window.onload = init;
</script>


<script>
function init() {
var vidDefer = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
for (var i=0; i<vidDefer.length; i++) {
if(vidDefer[i].getAttribute('data-src')) {
vidDefer[i].setAttribute('src',vidDefer[i].getAttribute('data-src'));
} } }
window.onload = init;
</script>
```

Comment: Hey just a point, why do you have 3 scripts all called `init`, how does the application know which one to use? Are they all on different pages? Are you just looking for some help combining all 3 into one function to be run from a `master page` or some `homepage`? Please clarify

Comment: I sent you explanation

Answer (score 0):

ok. so I try to defer images on my website... on 120 pages...
now, when i start, i was able to defer only images.

after that, I succeed defer the background-image: url().
but it is different JS as you see on the example I post before.

I succeed combine them but still, the JS no give full power.

after that, I start to fix again pages and i notice have google maps iframe
in couple of pages. ( something like 40 pages).

and I try to defer the iframe as well but it was too much for the javascript and the website loses the page load...

the JS needs to rewriting again...
i try a couple of variations as I post before, but none of them really improve the page load.

if we sucssed fix the Javascript at least put the 2 functions inside JS, JS of the background and images you will save me because I already edit all the 120 pages and the JS work and defer, but damage the page load because the JS is not written well.
(iframe is not so important like the images and the background)